The distribution of mass in the bullet cluster
Can someone point me to a database which contains the luminous and gas mass distribution of the bullet cluster?

The gas is luminous?

The hot gas is emitting X-rays...  I don't know about a "database" - I'm not sure what that means.  I can show you a picture that shows the distribution of stars, gas, and mass.  (it's on Wikipedia)

I am basically looking for the mass distribution in space, in ascii format, or maybe as a curve fit, which I can use for processing.

What I meant was that the "luminous and gas mass distributions" are basically the same thing. What differs is the mass distribution from gravitational lensing.

@ProfRob There are in principle three mass distributions: the luminous stellar mass of the galaxies (a small component, but coincident with the lensing mass), the luminous hot gas mass (the majority of the baryonic mass, offset from the lensing mass), and the (non-luminous) lensing mass.

You may find some relevant info regarding the mass distribution in this paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0702146
Eq.(65) gives the general solution for the mass distribution of an isothermal sphere for Newtonian gravity, Eq.(68) for a modified gravity law (MOG). This is applied to the bullet cluster by the data given in Table 2 (Table 3 for MOG gravity). The graphic results are shown in Fig.9

Those are general model mass distributions, not measured mass distributions for that cluster.

@PeterErwin As mentioned, Table 2 (page 14) in this paper gives the measured paraneters for this cluster. Inserting these into the general equations gives the mass distribution in this case.

Thanks, I believe this should help.
